# DotNetOpenOAuth Content-type

Tags: c#, oauth, dotnetopenauth, xero-api

I am tearing my the remainings of my hair off trying to solve an issue with DotNetOpenOAuth. Below are the details of the problem.

```
Consumer = new DesktopConsumer(xeroProviderDescription, _tokenManager);
var endPoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint(apiEndPoint, HttpDeliveryMethods.PostRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest);
var request = Consumer.PrepareAuthorizedRequest(endPoint, accessToken);
var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.ContentLength = content.Length;
```

This works perfectly fine, the server accepts the request and replies. Now, I want to switch to using xml to talk to the remote service (this is their prefered format over json) So I changed all the code into sending XML data instead of json and changed the content-type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as per the web service provider documentation. The problem now is that the service is returning 401 unauthorized request - Reason: invalid signature whenever `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is used

Questions:

1. Is the `Content-Type` taken into account when generating the oauth signature (I looked into the DotNetOpenOAuth source code with no luck)?
2. Anyone has ever encountered this issue and resolved it?

Comment: Do a request dump to see if it's username/password/accesstoken issue. Reading the OAuth provider's manual will help greatly.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I really doubt this is a toke issue because it perfectly works fine when the content type is null.